# ng build --prod dynamic variables get lost

Tags: angular, angular-cli, production, ng-modules, ng-build

i have a ngModule which uses [ngx-socket-io](https://github.com/rodgc/ngx-socket-io), i removed the unnecessary imports and injections :) as you can see i have commented some code which works like charm only in development build of application, as soon as i build the app using --prod those variables wont work anymore, if logged to the console the value is the same as static declaration yet SocketIoModule.forRoot(socketConfig) wont see them if build using --prod flag

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from "ngx-socket-io";
const socketConfig = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000',
    options: {
        query: {
            userId: "f9ae03de-f043-4704-882e-d269ee514805"
        }
    }
};

// const userId = (<any>window).MaxDuel.instance.userId;
// const socket = (<any>window).MaxDuel.instance.socket;
// const socketConfig = {url: socket, options: {query: {userId}}};
// const socketConfig2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(socketConfig));
console.log(socketConfig);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(socketConfig)
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but after commenting the variables and introducing the same copy but in static declaration, application starts working again!
as you can see i even serialized and deserialized to simulate a static declaration but again nothing!

the main problem is i need the userId on connection and that variable can not be static

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you run `ng build --prod` AOT compiler is used by default which means your code gets build on the server and being served to the user. At that point, there is no `window` object or `MaxDuel` object. So, you need to find another way. Lucky for you, there is!

I read the documentation of the library you use. There is another way to instantiate `Socket`. [Here you can read about it](https://github.com/rodgc/ngx-socket-io#using-multiple-sockets-with-different-end-points)

You need to create your own `Socket` and provide it.

```js
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable()
export class MySocket extends Socket {

    constructor() {
        super({url: window.MaxDuel.instance.socket, 
               options: {
                 query: {window.MaxDuel.instance.userId
              }});
    }

}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //components
  ],
  imports: [
    SocketIoModule,
    //...
  ],
  providers: [{
     provide: Socket, useClass: MySocket
  }],
  bootstrap: [/** AppComponent **/]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, you can inject `Socket` anywhere in your application and use it just fine.